# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Internal JSON-RPC error

Tags: ganache

I keep getting this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
  "stack": "CallError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Blockchain.simulateTransaction (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.0.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:72658)",
  "code": -32000,
  "name": "CallError",
  "data": "0x"
}
```

Comment: Its difficult to answer without looking into the code, there can be many reasons you are getting this error, any error in contract can through this. you should provide the code for function you are calling